# How to normalize data for LSTM?

Tags: python, normalization, lstm, keras

For learning purpose I am making simple dataset for LSTM, which can predict next number in sequence.

Here is my x value

```
x=[[i for i in range(j,j+5)] for j in range(1000)]
```

This will create an array [[0,1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5],...].

I have normalized x like this

```
for i in range(1000):
  for j in range(5):
    x[i][j]=x[i][j]/sum(x[i])
```

This is my y

```
y=[i+5 for i in range(1000)]
```

y is [5,6....]

I normalized y

```
y=y/sum(y)
```

In my single layer LSTM model after training this,when I try to predict sequence like 0,1,2,3,4 I get nan.
What I doing wrong?
According to me I think I am normalizing y wrong cuz sum(y) is very large so numbers tend to 0

Comment: Does the problem persist if you scale `x` and `y` to have mean 0 and standard deviation 1?